# Custom url scheme works only if the app is in the background?

Tags: ios, swift2, url-scheme

I have defined a custom url scheme for my iOS app so that it can be accessed from a website. When I type my custom url scheme in safari the app opens up but the following function in my AppDelegate does not get called:

```
 func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    print("Scheme: \(url.scheme)");
    print("Query: \(url.absoluteString)");
    return true;
}
```

It gets called only when the app is open and running in the background. I want that function to be called when I type in the url in safari and the app is not open.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, you can check if the launchOptions contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey. If you open your app using a scheme, it will be in that dictionary.

When the app is in the background, use openURL (as you do already).

Comment: I already tried printing out launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] and it just shows me nil.

Comment: Hm, that may be because it's not a String, but a NSURL.. What if you do this in your didFinishLaunching:     if let URL = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] as? NSURL { //print your URL value here } ?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't print out anything.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4:

I've founded that sometimes seems the app cannot open the url simply due to the time needed to build it's phisic infrastructure (especially if you use customized viewcontrollers or transitions). I've found this solution:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
             // your code
         }
         return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This almost sounds like the Custom URL settings haven't been setup correctly.

Do you definitely have these settings in your .plist file ?

[image]

With these settings in place, the `application` function should definitely get called, whenever your app gets launched.

More information here:

[Custom URLs](http://mikesknowledgebase.azurewebsites.net/pages/XCode/CustomURLs.htm)

Comment: the custom url scheme is already defined in the info.plist file, the scheme works it's just that the particular function that handles that scheme does not get called when the app is closed.

Comment: If the custom url would not have been setup correctly it wouldn't work at all, neither if the app is in the background, right? While that actually is working right now..

Comment: @Revant:  Hang on..  what is the actual problem ?  That the "application" function doesn't kick in when your app launches, or when "the app is closed" ?   It's not meant to get called when you close the app....

Comment: @MikeGledhill when the app is in closed state and I enter the url scheme in safari, the app opens up but it doesn't call the function defined in the AppDelegate.